# Custom OAuth2 provider with hello.js

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, hello.js

I'm working on custom OAuth2 Authorization Server (old initial version @ https://github.com/gvaduha/OAuth2CppLib) that compliant with RFC6749 and would like to use hello.js for one-page clients. What I've done to start with it:

1. created src/modules/myoauth.js

```js
(function(hello){
  hello.init({
    myoauth : {
        name : 'myoauth',

        oauth : {
            version : 2,
            auth : 'https://localhost/oauth2/authorize',
            grant : 'https://localhost/oauth2/token'
        },
        refresh : false,
        scope : {
            basic   : 'profile'
        },
        scope_delim : ' ',
        base : 'https://localhost/',
        get : {
            "me"    : "profile"
        },
    }
  });
})(hello);
```

2. added provider to demos/client_ids.js

```js
var CLIENT_IDS = {
    myoauth : 'OAuthTestClientId',
    windows : WINDOWS_CLIENT_ID,
    google : GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    facebook : FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID
};
```

3. added following lines to demos/login-events.html

```
<button onclick="login('myoauth')">Login myoauth</button>
<script src="../src/modules/myoauth.js"></script>
```

But all this for nothing. When I click login page following my server authentication then authorization then page reply with 302 redirect to

http://localhost/xxx/redirect.html#token_type=Bearer&access_token=XkGxfTVZWgdFuXTuc64du8DK375JurgOT2CDqv0QGd&expires_in=3600&

and when I closing popup page says

```js
callback:{
  "error": {
    "code": "cancelled",
    "message": "Login has been cancelled"
  },
  "network": "myoauth"
}auth:{
  "error": {
    "code": "cancelled",
    "message": "Login has been cancelled"
  },
  "network": "myoauth"
}auth.failed:{
  "error": {
    "code": "cancelled",
    "message": "Login has been cancelled"
  },
  "network": "myoauth"
}
```

What have I done wrong? BTW: Google works correct when I've changed it's id to point to my registered application client.

Answer (score 2):

The OAuth2 response does not appear to maintain the 'state' URI parameter in your example given.

Comment: Thanks, my server really has bug there! Could you extend error messages to clarify the source of problem?

Comment: Please mark this as the solution and create a ticket at https://github.com/mrswitch/hello.js/issues  :)